# can not add class name from app.component.css

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular and can not resolve how to add class names from CSS component
I'm writing a code demo that displays the weather condition of the city. If a city has cold temp, it will have blue color

I want to add class "express" to  tags but I have tried ngClass and className from Angular but it is not working

This is my Angular code

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'traning';
    public cities =[{
      name: 'montreal ',temp: -30
    },{
      name: 'toronto ', temp: 19
    },{
      name:'vancouver ',temp: -4
    }];
  ;
}
```

app.component.css

```
.express {
    color: rgb(13, 142, 255);
}
```

app.component.html

```
<head>
<link href="./app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>temp</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let city of cities">
        <td >{{city.name}}</td>
        <td class="express" *ngIf="city.temp <0; then cold; else cool" >{{city.temp}}</td>
        <ng-template #cold> cold</ng-template>
        <ng-template #cool>  cool</ng-template>
        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Angular demo run
[Demo of AngularJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGOjS.png)

I want to add class "express" to <>td> tags but do not know how

Comment: Just FYI, you are not using AngularJS: https://angularjs.org/ but Angular https://angular.io . They renamed the framework when moving from v1 to v2+ causing massive confusion =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an `*ngIf` directive with an explicit `then` clause, the `<td class="express">` element is ignored altogether in favor of the `<ng-template #cold>` element that is referenced from the `then cold` clause.

Take a look at this "[Using an external `then` template](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#using-an-external-then-template)" section of the NgIf Angular documentation. You'll notice, in the example it gives, the following line:

```
<div *ngIf="show; then thenBlock; else elseBlock">this is ignored</div>
```

As is suggested, the entire element to which the `*ngIf` directive is applied, is ignored when using an external `then` template (this is what you're doing).

It seems that you'd like to render the `<td class="express">` with dynamic content inside of it. That might look like the following:

```
<td class="express"> 
  {{city.temp}}
  <ng-container *ngIf="city.temp < 0; then cold; else cool"></ng-container>
  <ng-template #cold> cold</ng-template>
  <ng-template #cool> cool</ng-template>
</td>
```

Or using an implicit `then` template:

```
<td class="express"> 
  {{city.temp}}
  <div *ngIf="city.temp < 0; else cool"> cold</div>
  <ng-template #cool> cool</ng-template>
</td>`
```

Alternatively, if all you need is dynamic text, I might suggest the following:

```
<td class="express"> 
  {{city.temp}} {{city.temp < 0 ? "cold" : "cool"}}
</td>
```